# In EF Core, how can I perform a group by and select a list of comma separated values?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

In this little ASP.Net Core application, I am attempting to group students by their enrollment date and return the students' names in a comma separated string, as opposed to another kind of aggregation.

When using SQL, I've used the `stuff` function in the past, and I haven't been able to perform the equivalent operation as a subquery in LINQ.

Core won't allow me to perform client-side GroupBys, which I tried at first.

> Client side GroupBy is not supported.

I've tried the following code and received an InvalidOperationException:

```
IQueryable<EnrollmentDateGroup> data =
        _context.Students
        .GroupBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate)
        .Select(s => new EnrollmentDateGroup()
        {
          EnrollmentDate = s.Key,
          StudentCount = s.Count(),
          //BELOW IS NOT WORKING
          StudentNamesCSV = string.Join(",", s.Select(x => x.FirstMidName + " " + x.LastName))
        });
```

Another attempt and error message, moving away from using the already grouped data:

> SqlException: Column 'Student.EnrollmentDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
//ALSO NOT WORKING
...
StudentNamesCSV = string.Join(",", _context.Students
  .Where(x => x.EnrollmentDate == s.Key)
  .Select(x => x.FirstMidName + " " + x.LastName))
...
```

Any ideas are welcome! Thank you.

Comment: I take it you are using EF Core 3.x? You can do client `GroupBy` by explicitly indicating you want that: put `AsEnumerable()` before the `GroupBy`. Since `Student.EnrollmentDate` does not appear in your second query, I don't your error messages are matched to your queries properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below linq code:

```
var result = ((from uu in _context.Students.AsEnumerable()
                       select new​
                       {​
                           EnrollmentDate = uu.EnrollmentDate,​
                           FullName = uu.FirstMidName + " " + uu.LastName​
                       }).GroupBy(cc => cc.EnrollmentDate).​
                       Select(s => new EnrollmentDateGroup()​
                       {​
                           EnrollmentDate = s.Key,​
                           StudentCount = s.Count(),​
                           StudentNamesCSV = string.Join(",", s.Select(ee => ee.FullName).ToList())​
                       })​
                       ).ToList();
```

Comment: does this return all students to the client?

Comment: `_context.Students.AsEnumerable()` pulls everything from the database

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
    var data =  _context.Students
                .GroupBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate)
                .Select(s => new 
                {
                    Key = s.Key,
                    listOfStudents = s.ToList()
                }).ToList();
    var result = data.Select(s => new EnrollmentDateGroup
                             {
                                 EnrollmentDate = s.Key,
                                 StudentCount = s.listOfStudents.Count,
                                 //BELOW IS NOT WORKING
                                 StudentNamesCSV = string.Join(",", s.listOfStudents.Select(x => x.FirstMidName + " " + x.LastName))
                             });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Marzipancake